# Skimage subset, can't access image names in skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection

Tags: python, subset, scikit-image

I'm so confused. I read in multiple jpgs using skimage. If I use print(train[0:3]) it prints out image names, if I use print(train[0]), it prints out image numbers. I want to save the image names in a separate object, but I don't know how to subset a skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection and I can't find any info on it? I know this is probably something very simple. How do I access the image titles in a skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection to save them?

train = imread_collection("*.jpg", conserve_memory=True)

print(train[0:3])

- ['cat.0.jpg', 'cat.1.jpg', 'cat.2.jpg'] # output

print(train[0])

- [[[203 164  87]
  [203 164  87]
  [204 165  88]
  ... # output

train['cat.0.jpg'] gives "slicing must be with an int or slice object" error
train('cat.0.jpg') gives "'ImageCollection' object is not callable" error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is just one line of code. It reads the images in the current directory. My question is how to subset the skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection it creates.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the ImageCollection object is here:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.ImageCollection

Under "Attributes" you can see that there is a `files` attribute which contains the list of strings of all the files in the collection.

The different behavior between indexing with integers or slices is unfortunate, but thankfully you have a workaround with `train.files[0]`.